# Is there a way to capture inventory constraint within a job-shop model?

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I have been trying to capture some inventory constraints on the job-shop model.
Is there any built-in method in CP-SAT to solve the job-shop with inventory issue?

The inventory problem statement that I could think of is the following:

- Each task produces a certain quantity of resource once it is completed.
- Each quantity produced needs to be stored within an inventory.
- The inventory has limited capacity.
- The inventory is being released at a constant speed over time.

This statement makes the job-shop problem even more complex since I would need to capture the inventory at each point of time (hence, it would imply a time discretization that do not scale well).

I thought about the following formulation:

```
For t in T:
  inventory[t] = inventory[t-1] + input[t] - output[t]
  output[t] = inventory[t-1] * release_speed
  input[t] = sum(produced_quantity[task] for task in tasks if task_end == t)
```

Is there any other way to leverage built-in functions such as `model.AddCumulative`?

Answer (score 0):

The natural candidate would be `AddReservoirConstraint()`.
You will still need a time discretization for the continuous release over time.

You could still approximate by remove 10 every 10 time steps instead of 1 every step.

Comment: Thanks again Laurent, this is very helpful !

 I went through the description of AddReservoirConstraint(). 

In this use-case, the level_change is a variable (level_change[t]= stock[t] x release_speed). Is there any way to capture it ? Otherwise, seems like I should estimate a constant release, and use AddReservoirConstraintWithActive (in case  there is no need to release anything anymore when the reservoir is empty).

Comment: No, this one is not easy.